# Failing Cypress check on simple javascript program

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have a cypress check that fails with "Expected to find element: #renderlabel here; but never found it".

This is the cypress check code:

```
cy.get('#renderhere label').should('not.exist');
```

and this is my javascript code:

```
addEventToBut(3, function (event) {
    const htmlFormElement = document.createElement('form');
    htmlFormElement.noValidate = false;
    htmlFormElement.name = 'btn3form';
    const formGroup = document.createElement('div');
    formGroup.classList.add('form-group');
    const htmlTextInput = document.createElement('input');
    htmlTextInput.type = 'text';
    htmlTextInput.name = 'text';
    htmlTextInput.autocomplete = 'off';
    htmlTextInput.visibility = 'visible';
    htmlTextInput.autofocus = 'autofocus';
    htmlTextInput.id = 'btn3text';
    htmlTextInput.classList.add('form-control');
    htmlTextInput.placeholder = 'insert text';
    htmlTextInput.required = 'required';
    const htmlLabelElement = document.createElement('label');
    htmlLabelElement.for = 'btn3text';
    htmlLabelElement.innerText = 'Text';
    const htmlFormGroupElement = document.createElement('div');
    htmlFormGroupElement.classList.add('form-group');
    //htmlFormGroupElement.append(htmlLabelElement);
    htmlFormGroupElement.append(htmlTextInput);
    //create add and delete buttons
    const addBtn = document.createElement('button');
    addBtn.innerText = 'Add';
    addBtn.classList.add('btn', 'btn-primary');
    addBtn.type = 'submit';
    addBtn.visibility = 'visible';
    const delBtn = document.createElement('button');
    delBtn.innerText = 'Delete';
    delBtn.classList.add('btn', 'btn-secondary');
    delBtn.type = 'button';
    delBtn.visibility = 'visible';
    delBtn.id = 'delBtn';
    delBtn.value = 'remove';
    const btnFormGroupElement = document.createElement('div');
    btnFormGroupElement.classList.add('form-group');
    btnFormGroupElement.append(addBtn);
    btnFormGroupElement.append(delBtn);
    const listElement = document.createElement('ol');
    listElement.id = 'btn3list';
    htmlFormElement.append(htmlFormGroupElement);
    htmlFormElement.append(btnFormGroupElement);
    htmlFormElement.append(listElement);
    htmlFormElement.addEventListener(
        'submit',
        function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            const formData = new FormData(event.target);
            console.debug('I have downloaded the form!', {
                event,
                formData
            });
            document.getElementById('renderhere')
            var x = document.createElement("input");
            x.id = 'listbox';
            x.type = 'checkbox';
            x.class = 'checks';
            x.name = 'box'
            x.style.display = 'block';
            const listLabel = document.createElement('label');
            listLabel.for = 'listbox';
            listLabel.innerText = formData.get('text');
            listLabel.display = 'block';
            listLabel.id = 'boxID';
            listLabel.setAttribute('name','boxLabel');
            btn3list.appendChild(listLabel);
            btn3list.appendChild(x);
            htmlFormElement.append(htmlFormGroupElement);
            htmlFormElement.append(btnFormGroupElement);
            htmlFormElement.append(listElement);
        }
    );
    delBtn.addEventListener(
        'click',
        function () {
            var rmvCheckBoxes = document.getElementsByName('box');
            console.log(rmvCheckBoxes)
            for (var i = 0; i < rmvCheckBoxes.length; i++){
                for (var h = 0; h < rmvCheckBoxes.length; h++){
                    if(rmvCheckBoxes[h].checked){
                        console.log(rmvCheckBoxes.length);
                        console.log("break");
                        console.log(h);
                        removeElm(rmvCheckBoxes[h], h);
                    }
                }
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < rmvCheckBoxes.length; i++){
                for (var h = 0; h < rmvCheckBoxes.length; h++){
                    if(rmvCheckBoxes[h].checked){
                        console.log(rmvCheckBoxes.length);
                        console.log("break");
                        console.log(h);
                        removeElm(rmvCheckBoxes[h], h);
                    }
                }
            }
            removeElm(rmvCheckBoxes[0], 0)
        }
    );
    function removeElm(elm, i){
        var rmvLabels = document.getElementsByName('boxLabel');
        elm.parentElement.removeChild(rmvLabels[i]);
        elm.parentElement.removeChild(elm);
    }
    document
        .getElementById('renderhere')
        .childNodes.forEach(value => value.remove());
    document
        .getElementById('renderhere')
        .append(htmlFormElement);
});
```

Can anyone help please? I know my code is kinda scrappy I've only just started javascript and have been trying to advance my skills. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't see you rendering `renderlabel` anywhere in your javascript or cypress tests.   Are you missing some code?

Comment: its a div within the html div id="renderhere">
        The components for each task should render here when the relevant button is pressed.
    </div>
</div>

Comment: I dont understand it error either